# Cmake add_definitions as a local variable?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cmake task, which need to build two version library.

The source code of these two version is same, the only difference is, one with pre-compile `#define ALPHA_DEBUG` macro(which is `debug version`), which there is no(which is `production version`).

I know `add_definitions` is a cmake option can add `macro` in cmake.

So I do this:

```
SET(ALPHA_PG_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

SET(LIVE_PATH $ENV{HOME}/new_crypto)
SET(LIB_PATH $ENV{HOME}/lib_hft/)

macro(compile arg1)
  aux_source_directory(${arg1} ${arg1}_src)
  add_library(${arg1} SHARED ${${arg1}_src})
  set(debug OFF)
  if (${ARGC} GREATER 1)
    if(${ARGV1} STREQUAL "DEBUG")
      set(debug ON)
      # here is the point, i want the following setting enabled in debug only 
      add_definitions(-DALPHA_DEBUG)
      add_library(debug_${arg1} SHARED ${${arg1}_src})
      if (${ARGC} GREATER 2)
        set(list ${ARGN})
        list (SUBLIST list 1 -1 list_new)
        target_link_libraries(${arg1} ${list_new} config++)
        target_link_libraries(debug_${arg1} ${list_new} config++)
      else()
        target_link_libraries(${arg1} util_cpp config++)
        target_link_libraries(debug_${arg1} config++)
      endif()
    else()
      target_link_libraries(${arg1} ${ARGN} config++)
    endif()
  endif()
endmacro(compile)
```

The caller is:

```
compile(test_crypto)
compile(swap_arb DEBUG dl)
```

Let me explain the extra args:

If `arg[1] == DEBUG`, I add the `macro` to complie the `debug` verison
If not, the extra args will be the library i want to link.

But I found the add_definitions works globally, which means both the `production version` and `debug version` enable the `ALPHA_DEBUG` `macro`.

Could you let me know how to only enable the macro in `debug version`?

Comment: You know about `target_link_libraries`, to link libraries with a specific target. There are many more target-specific functions, like [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html). You can even set [properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) on [individual source files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html), like the [`COMPILE_DEFINITONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) property.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, that's the best answer.